# Angular - nested REST API calls only returning inner call

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

A ShoppingCart with ShoppingCartItems is fetched via an outer REST call, after which an Observable of the ShoppingCartItems makes the inner call to enhance the ShoppingCartItems with a Provider.

A tap(console.log) after the inner call, reveals that the contents of the ShoppingCart are as expected - with the 5 ShoppingCartItems enhanced with a Provider. Tapping the subscription however, returns 5 alerts each containing the Provider I wanted to add as a property of ShoppingCartItem.

It seems I am using the wrong mergeMap/concatMap/switchMap - or not doing a 'collect' of some sort at the end of one or both calls.

The calls:

```
  getShoppingCart$(userId: number): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
    return this.rest.getShoppingCart$(userId)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(
          (shoppingCart) => from(shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems)
            .pipe(
              concatMap(
                item => this.rest.getProviderByWine$(item.wine.id)
                  .pipe(
                    map(provider => item.provider = provider),
                  )
              ),
              // Returns ShoppingCart with Providers added
              tap(() => console.log('ShoppingCart: ' + JSON.stringify(shoppingCart)))
            )
        ),
      )
  }
```

The subscription:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shoppingCartService.getShoppingCart$(1037).subscribe(
      (shoppingCart: ShoppingCart) => {
        this.dataSourceShoppingCart = new NestedMatTableDataSource<ShoppingCartItem>(shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems);
        // Runs 5 times - each time displaying a Provider, not the ShoppingCart
        alert(JSON.stringify(shoppingCart))
      }
    );
  }
```

The actual REST calls:

```
  getShoppingCart$(userId: number): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
    return this.http.get<ShoppingCart>(this.getBaseUrl() + 'users/' + userId + '/shopping-cart');
  }

  getProviderByWine$(wineId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Provider>(this.getBaseUrl() + 'wine/' + wineId + '/provider');
  }
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Angular version is 8.

Comment: it seems you want to make subsequent calls where one call is dependent on result of outer call... use `switchMap` for that. you can read more about it here:-- https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-map-mergemap-switchmap-and-concatmap-833fc1fb09ff

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the logic into multiple functions makes the reasoning easier and reduces the amount of nesting.
Create a function that adds the provider to an item and a function that adds the enhanced items to a shopping cart.

You can use `forkJoin` to execute multiple independent observables in parallel.

```ts
getShoppingCart$(userId: number): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
  return this.rest.getShoppingCart$(userId).pipe(
    mergeMap(shoppingCart => enhanceShoppingCart(shoppingCart))
  );
}

// Add enhanced items to a shopping cart
private enhanceShoppingCart(shoppingCart: ShoppingCart): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
  // Map each shopping cart item to an Observable that adds the provider to it.
  const enhancedItems = shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems.map(item => enhanceItem(item))
  return forkJoin(enhancedItems).pipe(
    map(shoppingCartItems => ({ ...shoppingCart, shoppingCartItems }))
  );
}

// Add provider to an item
private enhanceItem(item: Item): Observable<Item> {
  return this.rest.getProviderByWine$(item.wine.id).pipe(
    map(provider => ({ ...item, provider }))
  );
}
```

Comment: This works as well - after I added this. in front of the calls to the private methods. At the level I'm at, this is perhaps more clear - even though I don't understand what is happening in the map() in enhanceItem()

Comment: `({ ...item, provider })` creates a new object, copies the properties from `item` into this object using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and assigns the `provider` object to the `provider` property using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). I used this syntax so that `enhanceShoppingCart` and `enhanceItem` don't mutate their input, which is often good practice.

Comment: Since both answers work and I cannot split the credit, I have picked one by random

Answer (score 0):

If there are 5 elements in the `shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems` array, then the observable `from(shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems)` will emit 5 times. That's what you're observing in the subscription.

If you're willing to replace the sequential requests using `concatMap` with parallel requests using `forkJoin`, you could try the following

```js
getShoppingCart$(userId: number): Observable < ShoppingCart > {
  return this.rest.getShoppingCart$(userId).pipe(
    mergeMap((shoppingCart) => 
      forkJoin(shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems.map(
        item => this.rest.getProviderByWine$(item.wine.id))
      ).pipe(
        map(providers => ({
          ...shoppingCart,
          shoppingCartItems: shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems.map((item, index) => ({
            ...item,
            provider: providers[index]
          }))
        }))
      );
    ),
    tap((kart) => console.log('ShoppingCart: ' + JSON.stringify(kart)))        // <-- we are priting the output from last operator not the `mergeMap`
  );
}
```

After the requests we are returning the transformed `shoppingCart` using the `map` operator. You could also use `concatMap` with `toArray()` operator for sequential requests, but 5 parallel requests wouldn't be huge overhead.

Comment: Certainly looks interesting - but I have a stupid question: I don't quite get what ...shoppingCart and ...item stand for?

Comment: @fridoo: Yeah, I've moved the map to `forkJoin`.

Comment: @morsor: It's the destructing assignment operator. You could find more info about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: There seems to be a problem inside the map regarding shoppingCart: An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.

Comment: @morsor: I've wrongfully accessed the property for the key. I've made two changes to the answer (`shoppingCartItems:` and `provider:`). Please check if it works now.

Comment: It works! When I corrected the provider index from i. Thanks a lot! Now I just need to understand the destructuring of ...shoppingCart

Comment: @morsor: You're welcome :) I overlooked the `index` as well. I've adjusted the answer. There are many good articles to be found on the destructuring topic.

Comment: Since both answers work and I cannot split the credit, I have picked one by random